# How to access User object in grails controller

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using spring security, and I need to get the User domain object in a controller.

If I call `SpringSecurityService.getPrincipal()`, I get back an object of type `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUser`.  However, what I'm looking for is the User domain object I've defined in my `Config.groovy` like so:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'project.auth.User'
```

How can I best get at the User domain object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Load the user instance using the cached id in the GrailsUser instance:

```
def user = User.get(SpringSecurityService.principal.id)
```